# How do I get Safari to respect inset for fixed positioning?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am currently creating a modal that sits on top of everything. The code seems to function perfectly fine in Chrome, but runs into an issue in Safari. The code block for creating this overlay is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div>
   This is my header
  </div>

  <div style="position: fixed; inset: 0; background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the result I get in Chrome which correctly covers the entirety of the header text so it's not visible.

[image]

This is the unexpected result I get in Safari since the inset occurs based on it's relative location.

[image]

How do I get Safari to have the same functionality as Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, oops. Safari doesn't support inset. I needed to change the code to just write top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0 instead.